# ¿Por qué mi impacto tiene un valor negativo?

Tags: soporte, perfil

Tengo un impacto de -205 y cada vez que participo en la comunidad sigue aumentando el valor negativo. ¿Por qué?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tu impacto es aproximadamente 205

Se muestra un `~` (tilde de la ñ) en lugar de un `-` (signo menos)

Comment: Pensé que era el signo negativo. Gracias por la aclaración! :D

Comment: Es una [virgulillla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=btCZ7EZ) :)